# python problem with multiprocessing and for

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

I'd like to check how much difference the for statement takes with multiprocessing. I don't think the for statement of the function do_something can be executed when I run the code. Please help me out on which part I did wrong.

The sum result kept on going to zero.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from sys import stdout

sum=0
def do_something():
    for i in range(1000):
        global sum  
        sum=sum+1
        
        progress = 100*(i+1)/1000   #process percentage

        stdout.write("\r ===== %d%% completed =====" % progress) #process percentage

        stdout.flush()
    stdout.write("\n")


# str=StringVar()
           
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    start = time.perf_counter()
 
    processes = []
    for _ in range(1):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something) ## 
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
 
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    
    finish = time.perf_counter()
 
    print(f'{round(finish-start,2)} sec completed')
    
print(sum)
```

- 

```
#Result
0.16 sec completed
0
```

Comment: Which operating system? The child process has its own memory space with its own `sum`. Changes in the child process will not be seen in the parent. If you want to return a value you need something like a queue or shared memory. `multirpocessing.Pool` does some of that work for you.

Comment: When I run it, I see " ===== 100% completed =====" along with the data you show (I'm on linux where a subprocess stdout is shared w/ its parent). I don't remember what Windows does off hand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As @tdelaney commented the subprocess created will be updating an instance of `sum` that "lives" in its own address space distinct from the address space of the main process that launched it. The usual solution would be to pass to `tdelaney` a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance that it can write the sum to and which the main process can then read (which should be done before joining the subprocess).

In the code below, however, I am using a `multiprocessing.Pipe` on which the `multiprocessing.Queue` is built. It is not as flexible as a queue in that it only readily supports a single reader and writer, but for this application that is all you need and it is a much better performer. The call to `Pipe()` returns two connections, one for sending objects and the other for receiving objects.

Note that in your code that the final `print` statement needs to be indented.

You should also refrain from naming variables the same as builtin functions, e.g. `sum`.

```py
import time
import multiprocessing
from sys import stdout

def do_something(send_conn):
    the_sum = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        the_sum = the_sum + 1

        progress = 100*(i+1)/1000   #process percentage

        stdout.write("\r ===== %d%% completed =====" % progress) #process percentage

        stdout.flush()
    stdout.write("\n")
    send_conn.send(the_sum)


# str=StringVar()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.perf_counter()

    read_conn, send_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something, args=(send_conn,)) ##
    p.start()
    the_sum = read_conn.recv()
    p.join()
    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'{round(finish-start,2)} sec completed')

    print(the_sum)
```

Prints:

```
 ===== 100% completed =====
0.16 sec completed
1000
```

Here is the same code using a `multiprocessing.Queue`:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing
from sys import stdout

def do_something(queue):
    the_sum = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        the_sum = the_sum + 1

        progress = 100*(i+1)/1000   #process percentage

        stdout.write("\r ===== %d%% completed =====" % progress) #process percentage

        stdout.flush()
    stdout.write("\n")
    queue.put(the_sum)


# str=StringVar()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.perf_counter()

    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something, args=(queue,)) ##
    p.start()
    the_sum = queue.get()
    p.join()
    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'{round(finish-start,2)} sec completed')

    print(the_sum)
```

Prints:

```
 ===== 100% completed =====
0.17 sec completed
1000
```